# How to disable the gnome3 of Fedora 15?

Tags: fedora-15, gnome3

I installed Fedora 15 on an old computer, and it uses the new gnome3 desktop.

But my computer is slow, so I want to disable it, continue to use the old traditional desktop.

How to do this?

Comment: With "the old traditional desktop", you mean Gnome 2? Why did you install Fedora 15 in the first place? It's one of the few major distributions to make the switch. Do you have to stick to Fedora? Or even use version 15 on this old machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the "fallback" mode. Open the user menu → *System Settings* → *System Info* → *Graphics* and enable "Forced Fallback Mode".